# What was the name of the main camera used to shoot Prometheus?

Tags: cinematography, prometheus

In the movie production of **Promtheus**, different techniques were used to make the film.

**The question is:**

***What was the name of the main camera used to film Prometheus?***

Comment: Additional attributions such cameras used in other movies of the same franchise are solid responses. Logos and trademarks also build the basis of the question, images and accreditations help to illustrate the answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the passage from a website found [here](https://techli.com/2012/06/technology-in-prometheus/) on the camera used:

> Scott originally was apprehensive about using digital visual effects because he believed that physical sets were more cost effective. After prodding from cinematographer Darius Wolski, Scott changed his mind and hired on MPC Film and Peter Jackson’s WETA Digital to lead the visual effects of the film.
>   The team hired 3ality Technica to provide the training and equipment for 3D filming, which included four Atom 3D rigs that were configured with Red Epic 3D cameras. These were used continuously during filming to deliver the depth of field required to give viewers the experience of being on the ship Prometheus. The fifth camera used was as steadicam. The decision to film in 3D added $10 million to the film’s budget.
>   Because 3D filming requires bright lighting, the team used visual effects to create the darkness inside the Prometheus ship that is characteristic of the Alien franchise. The lack of light in the films adds to the suspense and the claustrophobia that viewers expect.

Comment: Cool. Do you know how many names were on the credits for the most recent release?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you can mark it as correct or upvote as helpful.

Comment: For the 2017 release (Alien Covenant), see below for cast names: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2316204/

Comment: @Habatchii Was this helpful in anyway?

Comment: Yes. This was very helpful. It actually aligned solid state with digital with in depth focus. Great. The question was directing towards equipment and the answer as well.

Comment: Awesome, so now you can mark the answer as correct...and if you want, upvote as useful. Glad to help anyday :)